# nav controls for a for loop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a simple animation fading in and out each list item in an unordered list.  The HTML markup is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>first par</li>
  <li>second par</li>
  <li>third par</li>
</ul>

<div></div>
```

The empty div will contain buttons for the nav controls dynamically via jquery.

The script is as follows:

```
<script>

var ul = $('ul'), li = $('ul li'), li_length = li.length, div = $('div');

//hides all list items
li.hide();

function play (eq){
  eq = (eq===undefined) ? 0 : eq; 

  for(i=eq, d=0; i<li_length; i++, d+=3000){
    li.eq(i).delay(d).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  }
}

//This dynamically appends the nav buttons in the div
li.each(function(i){
  div.append('<button> '+ i + '</button>');
})

//the normal animation going through each list item, fading in and out
play();

var btn = $('div button');

//each button when clicked should animate the corresponding list item (fadein and out), then the next 
li.each(function(i){
   btn.eq(i).click(function(){
     li.stop(true, true);
     li.hide();
     play(i);
   })
})

</script>
```

When `play()` runs, it does the job. However when you click any nav button, e.g. 2nd list item is playing then you click the button 1 (essentially calls `play(1)`), the for loop (from `play()`) still seems to be playing though I have stopped the animation of all list items using `.stop()`. The result is overlapping animations. I am a noob and am clueless as how to approach this so that there will be no overlap in animations. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will continue to run regardless of you stopping the current animation:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Instead of `delay` you should use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and cancel it inside your `click` handler:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { [fadeIn/fadeOut] }, delayDuration);
```

Then from your `click` handler:

```
btn.eq(i).click(function() {
    ...
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

The way you have `play` setup to run, you'd need to set and cancel the timeout for each `li` animation.

**AMENDED**

Using `setTimeout`, some of your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
function play (eq){
    var
        eq = eq || 0,
        i, d; 

    for(i=eq, d=0; i<li_length; i++, d+=3000){

        // store the timeoutID returned by setTimeout on the li itself
        li.data('timeoutId', setTimeout(function() {
                li.eq(i).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
            }, d)
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your `click` handler:

```
li.each(function(i){
    btn.eq(i).click(function(){
        li.stop(true, true);
        li.hide();

        // grab the timeoutId and clear it
        clearTimeout(parseInt(li.data('timeoutId'), 10));

        play(i);
    });
});
```

You may need an additional call to `setTimeout` for the `delay` between the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`, but hopefully you get the point from the above code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help @Andre. Is there a way to keep the setTimeout inside the for loop? Like perhaps making 3 setTimeout variables dynamically? e.g. timeout1, timeout2... I am putting it inside the loop so that even if there are more li items added in the HTML, there will be no need to revise the script. If I make 3 different setTimeout variables manually, it may defeat my purpose.

Comment: There are a few ways you can track your timeout Ids. You could store them in an array (e.g., `var myTimeoutIds = []; ... myTimeoutIds.push(setTimeout(...));`) or directly on the `li`s themselves (e.g., `li.data('timeoutId', setTimeout(...));`) or something entirely different.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this: `//lets say these were pushed dynamically var timeouts = ['to1', 'to2', 'to3']; for(i=eq, d=0, t=0; i<li_length; i++, d+=3000, t++){timeouts[t] = setTimeout(function(){ li.eq(i).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);}, d);}` to no avail. I believe I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: I've amended my answer to include a code example. A word of caution: this thread is starting to deviate away from original question. If you're satisfied with my explanation of the original issue please mark my answer as correct and start a new thread for any different questions.

Comment: I apologize, I voted up since I think setTimeout is being on the right track. I did exactly as you said, unfortunately it didn't work. Nothing is fading in at all. I also changed the part "clearInterval" to "clearTimeout", but still it doesn't seem to work. Any further help would be appreciated.